# Three.js load json string

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js.......

I know there's a JSONLoader to load JSON from a file/url. But is it possible to load a JSON object already in the current file?

for instance if I have a mesh in a JSON object
can I directly use it?

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992147/three-js-include-mesh-data-in-code/27996338#27996338

Comment: That worked! Thanks WestLangley - I don't have enough rep to mark as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load a JSON object directly like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

var model = loader.parse( myJSONObject );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, model.materials[ 0 ] );

scene.add( mesh );
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992147/three-js-include-mesh-data-in-code/27996338#27996338).

three.js r.73